# SyntaxError: invalid syntax while assigning the value to a variable while the code runs fine if it ran individually

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am running this query on python terminal and it executes fine.

```
>>> exec(open("GeneratePassword.py").read())
HkdgtRf
```

However when I try to assign that value to a variable I am getting this error.

```
>>> xx = exec(open("GeneratePassword.py").read())
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    xx = exec(open("GeneratePassword.py").read())
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

`exec` in Python 2 is a statement, not a function.  It doesn't return anything.  The right way to do what you're doing is to make it a Python module, so you can do:

```
import GeneratePassword
xx = GeneratePassword.generate()
```

Comment: Can I import a file which is not in the same location?

Comment: As long as its location is on the Python path (`sys.path`), of course.  That's how you get the standard packages, after all.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to import. However now the question is how I need to run it. Since I need to run the entire python file itself with passing arguments, like <python GeneratePassword.py -c -l 12 > something like that

Comment: @user1728730 if you need with parameters then maybe use `subprocess.run()`. OR put code in function so you could run this function with parameters - and normally it could use `if __name__ == "__main__":` to run code which get parameters from `sys.argv` (or usign module `argparse` and run the same function with parameters.

Comment: @user1728730 You essentially make the whole file into a function.  Add a small `if __name__ == '__main__':` section where you parse command-line parameters and convert them into parameters to your big function. That will let you call it from the command line, OR import it into another module.

Answer (score -2):

Use the python3 For solve this type of Error

Comment: Our environment runs on 2.7.. It's not up to me to upgrade it. Otherwise, I would have.